# excel vba button move to chosen cell

Tags: vba, excel, gantt-chart

I have a **BIG** Excel table (Daily Gantt Chart)
and I need a button use which I can choose date.
like a Vlookup but instead of bringing the data to me, I want to go to the data.
like a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> , but thats already installed.

I looked everywhere for a VBA code for this so im sorry in advance that I don't have my own.

[image]

Comment: try giving feedback and give credit to previous answers you got on previous questions on SO. You gave **0** from 6 so far, this will not attract users to assist you

Comment: sorrt, im still new here. how do i do that?

Comment: Go to those posts, and next to the good answers u got, mark the **V** next to them

Comment: ok, will do!! thanks !!